# Reloading my os on my laptop

Tags: system-installation

How do I install Ubuntu on a formatted hard drive so that when re installed into my laptop the computer boots in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

See [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) page for how to install ubuntu on a formatted hard drive.